# Openbox doesn't seem to have correct environment variables set

Tags: debian, x11, environment-variables, openbox, gdm

I've installed Debian 7.0, and then installed Openbox on top of it.

I've got some executable files in `~/bin`, and this line in my `.bashrc` and `.profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I can normally execute the programs when I'm using the terminal, but when I'm using Openbox keyboard shortcuts, configured in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`, then Openbox complains about not being able to find a file or a directory.

What can I do to have Openbox use the correct `$PATH`?

Comment: Do you log in in text mode or graphical mode? If in graphical mode, under what display manager? If in text mode, how do you start the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your environment for Openbox in the `~/.config/openbox/environment`.

Just add

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"; export PATH
```

in there.